# $scope not working on console

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

AngularJS Developer Guides on scope says that we can examine the scope by typing $scope on console.

> To examine the scope in the debugger:
>
> 1.Right click on the element of interest in your browser and select
>   'inspect element'. You should see the browser debugger with the
>   element you clicked on highlighted.
>
> 2.The debugger allows you to access the currently selected element in
>   the console as $0 variable.
>
> 3.To retrieve the associated scope in console execute:
>   angular.element($0).scope() or just type $scope

But when I'm typing $scope on console it says

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $scope is not defined
>       at :1:1

Here is the [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) for reference.

app.js look like this

```
var app=angular.module("app",[]);
app.controller("ctrl",['$scope','demoservice',function($scope,demoservice){
  console.log(demoservice);
  $scope.ser=demoservice;
}]);

app.service("demoservice",[function (){
  this.name="Himanshu";
}]);
```

Someone is asking for code so here is [CodePen](https://codepen.io/NaveenPen/pen/ZLBgZx) on which same error is coming.

Comment: Not very fair to downvote. This is literally what the documentation says

Comment: if you inspect by a break point in console when the execution is in process and $scope is in memory i.e your breakpoint is inside an controller or function you can access $scope, because as $scope is wrapped inside controller its not global to use in console as a common variable

Comment: It's fair as long as they didn't show us what they try to do. Maybe they just created a js file with one line - `console.log($scope);` ($scope is not defined at : __1:1__ )? If the user show us their code i'll might revert my vote

Comment: I imagine OP followed the instructions to the letter (as I have just tried to do as well) and found the error. This simply needs to be reported as an issue to the Angular team

Comment: Progress https://github.com/angular/angular.js/pull/4884#issuecomment-273704857

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$scope is a reference variable inside controller hence writing $scope on console will not provide an access as its not a global variable but private to a scope. So if you need to access $scope variable you need to access it in certain execution scope consider the following example

[image]

A breakpoint has been kept in the middle of execution content, so here now as $scope is in memory we can use it in console like this

[image]

So in order to inspect $scope you have to be in middle of execution perhaps not just to $scope but this applies for any js code variable unless its global cannot be accessed in window console.

other than that to use more friendly angular JS debugging you can also use [angular batarang](https://github.com/angular/batarang) an add on to chrome

Answer (score 1):

Pick an element from the HTML and in the console tab execute `angular.element($0).scope();` this the statement you will get the scope of that element.

or

You can install in-inspect chrome plugin. and use `$s`
 in the console to get the scope of the element.

Comment: angular.element($0).scope(); thing I know. But Developer Guides also state that I can also use $scope. That's my question why $scope not working.

Comment: @Naveen for accessign $scope you have to be under execution scope see my answer or else for a better debugging for angular use angular-batarang

Comment: In debugging mode, all the variables that are available in the closure at that debugging point will be accessible in the console. 
For suppose if the executing function has variables $scope, variable1, variable2. all these values will be available on console(in debugging mode).